# REGEX to print every word in reverse

Tags: php, regex

Could anyone please help me with the regex of reversing each word in a string?

*Sample input:*

```
Hello how are you my friend?
```

*Desired Output*

```
olleH woh era uoy ym ?dneirf
```

**I want to implement this in PHP.**

Comment: What makes you think this can be done only using regular expressions?

Comment: why not use [strrev()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php)?

Comment: Hopefully you people must have read my question properly. I have never mentioned that it can only be done using REGEX. I want a solution using REGEX because it is fast. Btw, @Teneff: i have the bit common sense that the strrev function would not do the job as i mentioned in the question.

Comment: Did you time both of the solutions? I'm not sure if regex would win on speed...

Comment: Why would regex be faster than native PHP functions that do the same thing?

Comment: Regular expressions are slow. Nobody should ever choose regular expressions for performance reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This gives you almost what you want.

If it isn't close enough, look into [Blender's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155251/regex-to-print-every-word-in-reverse/6155299#6155299) of exploding on spaces.

```
preg_replace_callback('/\b(\w+)\b/', function($match) {
    return strrev($match[1]);
}, $str);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/K4wDUI).

You can reverse text using plain regex (and some string functions) but it is ugly...

```
$length = strlen($str);

echo preg_replace(
         '/' . str_repeat('(.)', $length) . '/s',
         '$' . join('$', range($length, 1)),
         $str
     );
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/2r9qXx).

The code sample above is for demonstration only. Please do not ever use it :)

Comment: @Jared Thanks for edit, maybe I've been watching too much Futurama :P

Comment: I'm glad you added the "demonstration only" line. Regular expressions are the worst way to tackle this problem, despite the question's arbitrary requirement :|

Answer (score 2):

That can't be done in pure regex, sorry.

Here's a possibly-working PHP script:

```
$exploded = explode(' ', $string);
$temp = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count(exploded); $i++) {
  $temp[] = strrev(exploded[i]);
}

$temp = implode(' ', $temp);
```

Comment: @Coding-Freak Please be courteous to your Stack Overflow peers.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. @Alex's answer isn't completely done in regex, as a callback function is used to reverse the actual strings. You should be a bit clearer when saying "with regex", as I assumed you meant with *only* regex.

Comment: Your explode call is missing the delimiter parameter. `explode(' ', $string)`. You'd probably also want to put the spaces back when concatenating $temp.

Comment: @cOle2, thanks. Brain sees the space, but nobody else does ;)

Comment: +1 from me. You may want to `join()` again at the end, or you will get a trailing space.

Comment: @alex, thanks. Haven't coded PHP in a while, so still getting used to the endless array of functions...

Comment: @all - I am very sorry to all of you. I shouldn't have over reacted in such a manner. Afterall you people are giving your valuable time for rookies like us. THANKS A LOT. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not Regex, but this works:

```
<?php

function reverseWords($text) {
    $words = explode(' ', $text);
    $c_words = count($words);
    $outtext = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $c_words; $i++) {
        if ($i !== 0) $outtext .= " ";
        $length = strlen($words[$i]);
        for ($p = $length-1; $p >= 0; $p--) {
            $outtext .= substr($words[$i], $p, 1);
            $start--;
        }
    }
    return $outtext;
}

echo reverseWords("This is a test.");

?>
```

https://ideone.com/WUtzJ

Now, I forgot about `strrev()`, so that would shorten it a bit.

**EDIT**

Using `strrev()`:

```
<?php

function reverseWords($text) {
    $words = explode(' ', $text);
    $c_words = count($words);
    $outtext = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $c_words; $i++) {
        if ($i !== 0) $outtext .= " ";
        $outtext .= strrev($words[$i]);
    }
    return $outtext;
}

echo reverseWords("This is a test.");

?>
```

https://ideone.com/NT7A5

Answer (score 0):

This is *extremely* trivial to accomplish without a regular expression, and I see a lot of massive solutions here, so I thought I'd post a one-liner:

```
$rev = implode(' ', array_map('strrev', explode(' ', $string)));
```